# R random forest by sensitivity

Tags: r, random-forest

Is it possible to run a supervised classification random forest maximizing sensitivity (TP/(TP+FN))?
As far as I know, Accuracy or Kappa are the metric.
Below, an real example where both Kappa and Accuracy miss to evaluate the model as desired. As pointed in the answer and comments (@Hanjo and @Aaron), sensitivity alone is not a good metric.

```
      0    1     T  
0  1213   50  1263  
1   608   63   671  
T  1821  113  1934  

> Precisao(prev_table)
[1] "accuracy(TP+TN/T)= 0.66"
[1] "precision(TP/TP+FP)= 0.558"
[1] "sensitivity(TP/TP+FN)= 0.0939"
[1] "positive= 671 0.347"
[1] "negative= 1263 0.653"
[1] "predicted positive= 113 0.0584"
[1] "predicted negative= 1821 0.942"
[1] "Total= 1934"
```

This real x predicted results are poor to the goal.

Comment: You could, but why specifically sensitivity? Look into the 'caret` library and under training model, set `metric` to sensitivity. I think `kappa` is a much better evaluation of the models performance as it takes into account class imbalances

Comment: @HanjoJo'burgOdendaal, it seems, by docs, that only Accuracy and Kappa are the possible metrics.

Answer (score 3):

let me elaborate for you on why choosing "sensitivity" or "specificity" as the performance metric might not be a good idea, and why I say you must perhaps go for `kappa` (especially in unbalanced class predictions)

Imagine we have the following dataset and prediction outcomes:

```
x   Outcome Prediction
0.515925884 1   1
0.416949071 0   1
0.112185499 0   1
0.557334124 0   1
0.599717812 0   1
0.272965861 1   1
0.898911346 0   1
0.347428065 0   1
```

If the model predicted a 1 on all observations, you would have a 100% sensitivity and would falsely presume that the model was doing well. The same is true if the model predicted all outcomes as 0, which relates to 100% specificity. But does this mean the model is well tuned? Obviously not, as a simple rule of 'predicting' all outcomes as true positives will give you specificity of 100%. Now, `kappa` uses the following measurement of model performance:

*The Kappa statistic (or value) is a metric that compares an Observed Accuracy with an Expected Accuracy (random chance)*. This is a much more representative measure of the performance of your model. A nice answer to explain this can be found here [Stats Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82162/kappa-statistic-in-plain-english)

Comment: In practice, it is not. How I have lots of negatives, the model evaluate as a good answer lots of predicted negative. It is important to focus on Sensitivity: the objective of the the model is NOT to predict a false negative, in other words, be eficient in a positive prediction. Predictions made with Kappa or Accuracy give 3 different cases in a 5000 sample. Below an illustration.

Comment: What Hanjo is saying though, is you don't need random forests to maximize sensitivity. Simply predict 1 for everything, done. If that's not what you want to do, you need some metric that has a tradeoff in it.

Comment: If you choose Sensitivity as a metric, your model will learn to predict 1 on all questions, no matter the input - as when you were training it, you werent punishing it for guessing 1 on questions which were 0 in reality. i.e no matter the x variable inputs, your model will always predict 1.